# Reverse engineer delorme PN60w firmware to fix GPS rollover

Tags: gps, reverse-engineering, gps-time

On April 6 2019 the second rollover event occurred in the GPS system.  GPS time stamps consist of a 10 bit week number and seconds into the week.   The first rollover was in August 1999.

I would expect that there is a constant in the firmware to correct for this, and it needs to be updated.

Alas: Delorme has been absorbed by Garmin and since discontinued, and Garmin has seized on this as an opportunity to sell new devices to people.  There is no firmware update to correct this.

How reasonable is it to reverse engineer the firmware to find and fix this?

Firmware downloads are available here:

https://support.garmin.com/ms-MY/?faq=vWZtj31HFN15V85bzseCe7

Note that this does not affect the ability to navigate, but all timestamps are off by 7 * 1024 days in the past.

Correction:  After 2 hours sitting under an open sky, it is still reporting, "No fix"

Answer (score 0):

That was fast.

Garmin has put a new firmware version on their website here:

https://support.garmin.com/en-US/?faq=dXCDWk3aIZ3A0Ly9z8uym5&productID=585533&searchQuery=firmware&tab=topics

Applied, and indeed it fixes the issue.